# RTRIM causing "the multipart identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel as if the following should work. Trying to right trim and add `login_name` and `custr_id` on the same row with a `':'` in between them.

But I'm getting

> multipart identifiers could not be bound on everything such as
> l.login_name, c.custr_id, etc..

```
SELECT
rtrim(l.login_name)+':'+
rtrim(c.custr_id)
FROM
customer c
LEFT JOIN login l
ON l.custr_id = c.custr_id
WHERE
c.custr_id=777
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What makes you think its the `rtrim` thats causing the problem?

Comment: *"The multi-part identifier could not be bound."* is when you are trying to use 2+ part naming with a qualifier that doesn't exist in the `FROM`. For example `SELECT db.name FROM sys.databases d;` would return the error as `databases` is aliased as `d`, not `db`. Your SQL above has no such problem. It appears there's something you aren't telling us here.

Comment: @Larnu, there is sadly, nothing that I am leaving out here. The select statement without `rtrim` works fine. The moment I add it as above, is when the multi-part identifier problems appear.

Comment: The select statement without rtrim doesn't mention `login.login_name` column. Check the col name is valid.

Comment: Then you need to provide an [mre], @Ransome , the above works fine. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccae09762a27a5901ddc573c8c984d73)

Comment: Perhaps your query contains similar characters, but from different languages. For example, "c" character or "l" character.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart SSMS.  Sometimes that alone will fix the issue.  For me, restarting SSMS fixed it.

Comment: As already noted, RTRIM will not cause this error. There is some detail you omit or do not understand that causes the problem. It could be that your query window is not using the correct database, that you have the same table in multiple databases but with different columns, that you have multiple schemas containing these tables with different columns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

it is probably failing if something is NULL.  I would apply a coalesce() such as

```
rtrim(coalesce(l.login_name, ''))+':'+
rtrim(coalesce(c.custr_id, ''))
```

Comment: COALESCE will avoid or fix OP's error.